# Create Issue with Jira

Tags: c#, json, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

Im making an application where users can post issues and more. I am able to post an issue via Postman using basic auth and posting this raw application/json

**UPDATE**
I have made progress, with this method i get through the basic auth is invalid error. But... I still have a 400 Bad request error. The code now is:

```
public async Task<string> PostIssueAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        string data = @"{
                'fields': {
                   'project':
                   {
                        'key': 'TEST'
                   },
                   'summary': 'zfasf',
                   'description': 'Creating an issue while setting custom field values via projhect ',
                   'issuetype': {
                        'name': 'Fault'
                   }
                        }
                    }";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(Constants.JiraUrl + "rest/api/latest/issue");
        var cred = GetEncodedCredentials(username, password);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", cred);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            var test = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**The error:**
In the else statement I use the ReadAsStringAsync to see the error. The error is: "{"errorMessages":["Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@ae77320; line: 2, column: 7]"]}"

I think it goes wrong in the data file. I'll update when i get further.

Comment: Could you post the output of your var json into the question so I can help you better?

Comment: `= new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic"` <- try removing the space.

Comment: @Eldar the Basic auth header requires a space

Comment: @craigster added var json at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it :). It was the data file. This should work if you use it. I also added the GetEncodedCredentiels method so you can use that as well. Thank you all for your help!!

**UPDATE**
I have made progress, with this method i get through the basic auth is invalid error. But... I still have a 400 Bad request error. The code now is:

```
public async Task<string> PostIssueAsync(string username, string password)
    {
                    string data = @"{
                ""fields"": {
                   ""project"":
                   {
                        ""key"": ""TEST""
                   },
                   ""summary"": ""test"",
                   ""description"": ""Creating an issue while setting custom field values via projhect"",
                   ""issuetype"": {
                        ""name"": ""Fault""
                   }
                        }
                    }";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(Constants.JiraUrl + "rest/api/latest/issue");
        var cred = GetEncodedCredentials(username, password);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", cred);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            var test = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

**GetEncodedCredentiels method:**

```
        private static string GetEncodedCredentials(string userid, string password)
    {
        string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", userid, password);
        byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need the "Encoding.ASCII" part instead of "Encoding.UTF8".

Also converting it to Byte Array might help.

This code works for me.

```
    System.Net.WebClient cli = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string authInfo = My.Settings.username + ":" + My.Settings.password;
    cli.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo)));
    cli.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonstringpayload);
    webClient.UploadDataAsync("http://support.example.com:8080/rest/" + url, "POST", bytes);
```

Comment: I still get the "The format of value 'Basic is invalid" as an error. Therefor i cannot go further in the method and check if it uploads the problem